# null pointer exception on getNodeValue() when parsing XML web page - android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I looked over several of the answers posted here, but I can't find the answer I need. It may have to do with the web site itself, but I don't think it is.
I'm trying to parse an XML on a web site and I'm getting a **null pointer exception** error.

I run the parsing is a separate thread following Google demand when reading from the web.

please see my code and try to help.

```
class BackgroundTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

protected String[] doInBackground(String... url) {
    new HttpGet();
    new StringBuffer();
    InputStream is = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;

    try {
        //Log.d("eyal", "URL: " + boiUrl);
        URL url1 = new URL("http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml");
        con = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.connect();
        is = con.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(is);
        NodeList lastVld = doc.getElementsByTagName("LAST_UPDATE");
        String lastV = lastVld.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get the error on the last line.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where in your code are you getting the NPE?

Comment: Ryan J, answer to your question- In the line lastVld.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
InputStream is = null;
HttpURLConnection con = null;

try {
    URL url1 = new URL("http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml");
    con = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.connect();
    is = con.getInputStream();
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(is);
    NodeList lastVld = doc.getElementsByTagName("LAST_UPDATE");

    Element elem = (Element) lastVld.item(0);
    String lastV = elem.getTextContent();
    System.out.println(lastV);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I verified I was getting good content by adding a transformer to print out the results to the console.

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer xform = tFactory.newTransformer();

xform.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

There was a couple times I tried running where `elem` came out null, which I think had something to do with some bad content being retrieved from the URL. This was the content that was printed by the transformer.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>document.cookie='iiiiiii=11a887d6iiiiiii_11a887d6; path=/';window.location.href=window.location.href;</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed that if I had this file open in my browser, the code would all of a sudden quit working until I refreshed the page, then it started giving me the right output.

I suspect there's an issue with something at this URL, because when it works properly, this code works fine.

Good luck...

Comment: Thank you for the effort. You are right, there was a problem with the web site. It was fixed and it is working now. I added V for you on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one LAST_UPDATE tag in your xml and it has an inner value, so try just using the node value from the [Node Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) you get from `item(0)`

```
 String lastV = lastVld.item(0).getNodeValue();
```

HTHs

Comment: Sorry, still not working. Are you able to run this code? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no node returned for that tag name.  You may want to first check the size of the lastVld and then try to access the items in there.

Comment: There is only one LAST_UPDATE node in this web site, I don't understand your comment.